# Use python and Accessing the request GITUB authenticated URL that response JSON file after that we have parse the JSON to CSV file format

Tags: python, github

I am new to python code. We are requesting the GitHub URL and Response is JSON. We have to parse the Json to filter out the labels that need to store in the CSV format as specific labels. We have authentication token that we use it for request of the URL. could you please provide the coding the above scenario

Comment: You seem to be in the wrong place. We here in SO don't provide code. This is for questions, and for that, you need to have your own code.

Comment: Please anyone provide the code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general and since you didn't include any code, it seems like you are just looking for a straightforward answer.

I can't give you that, but the below code should get you started on converting a json into a python object, looking for a specific keyword `label` and writing it to a cvs file.

```
import json
x = json.loads(your_json_object)
for label in x:

with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as file:
  for label in x:
      file.write("{}, ".format(label))
```

Comment: Actually we need to hit URL request where the response should be JSON, How to write the code for request and response ?